# can't get permissions with facebook sdk javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

```
FB.login(function(response) { 
if (response.authResponse) {
console.log('logged in');
} else {
console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
},{scope: 'email,user_friends,public_profile'});
```

I can log into facebook like this but it doesn't let me have the permissions that i'm asking for.  I've tried perms instead of scope but that didn't seem to do anything.  Also my console.log doesn't seem to work either.  Is there something i have to do before i can get the permission.

Comment: How do you know that you don't get the permissions you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that at the first time you were testing you were requesting only 'email', than you've figured you'd need more permissions.

Turns out that if you don't logout and then login again, it won't ask you for the rest of the permissions.

You may wanna try logout before test it again.